# How can I prove that an invented operation works with negative numbers?

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, binary-operations

Just out of curiosity I tried making a new operation to see its properties. It is like a variation of addition that works like this:

a ¨ b = a + b - 1

For example, I found that it has the commutative property and that

a ¨ b ¨ c ¨ d ... = a + b + c + d + ... - [number of operations done]

Then I tried to make the equivalent of the multiplication in terms of this operation. The same way as a*b is a+a+a+a...(b times), a " b = a ¨ a ¨ a ... (b times)

From here I find that

a " b = ab - b - 1

**What I can't figure out is whether this formula can also be applied for negative numbers or zero.**

By the way, I found that it doesn't have the commutative property.

Since it is a negative number I don't know what it would mean to repeat the first operation a negative number of times. I know that for example 5*(-3) equals -15 because it is the same as doing - 3 - 3 - 3 ... (five times), but since my operation does not have a commutative property I don't know how to look at this problem.

I realise this question might be silly but I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe, you should rather look at your operation in terms of a group, that is, consider the tuple $(\mathbb R,¨)$ and check if it is a group. If it is, you may consider the inverse of each element $a\in\mathbb R$ and denote it as, say, $\bar a$. Then, writing $a"(-b)$ may also be interpreted as $\bar a" b$.

Comment: As explained in the dupe, this is a special case of transport of structure. See the linked posts in the dupe for many further examples.